# French accent characters issue when redirecting output in a Batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, encoding, console

I am using Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64 French.

Console (cmd.exe) :

```
> chcp
Page de codes active : 850

> net start MyService
Le service ne répond pas à la fonction de maintenance.
Vous obtiendrez une aide supplémentaire en entrant NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

Batch (UTF-8) :

```
@call :begin 1>log.txt 2>&1
@exit /b
:begin 

@chcp
@net start MyService
```

log.txt (ANSI) :

```
Page de codes activeÿ: 850

Le service ne r‚pond pas … la fonction de maintenance.
Vous obtiendrez une aide suppl‚mentaire en entrant NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

How to force the Batch to have the same output as the Console (print the French characters properly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this way with a temporary file and redirect it with this command :

`CMD /U /C Type tmplog.txt>log.txt` to read unicode :

---

```bat
@echo off
@call :begin
@call :begin 1>tmplog.txt 2>&1
CMD /U /C Type tmplog.txt>log.txt
Del tmplog.txt
Start "" /MAX log.txt
pause & exit /b

::--------------------------
:begin
net start Myservice
@exit /b
::--------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the top of the batch use:

```
chcp 1252 >nul
```

Next in notepad go to the File menu \ Save as, in codification choose "ANSI", click yes to substitute current file. Done.

[image]

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: try 863 instead of 1252...

Comment: change the encoding of the file to `863` works even without `chcp`